# IIS7 asp.net error while accessing webpage . "Cannot execute a program"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am getting the following error on accesign an application.
The app is installed on IIS7 windows server 2008

Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\vbc.exe" /noconfig @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\entitymanager\fc119101\f785f7e5\ugj1_w_e.cmdline".

Any help is much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled asp.net which fixed the issue.
I appretiate the suggestions provided

Comment: run the command below for the version of the .Net u want to install from "asp.net_regiis -i"  e.g C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is a permissons issue somewhere.  Does this KB apply to your situation?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315904

Note, I know this KB references csc.exe, but it's still basicaly the same message, seeing as csc.exe is the c# compiler and vbc.exe is the VB.net complier.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the configuration of currently used Application Pool.